# SQL syntax error (COUNT (DISTINCT .. ))

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I try to use COUNT (DISTINCT .. )) in my SQL syntax, this is my SQL syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT ID)
FROM teaches
WHERE semester = 'Spring' AND year = 2010;
```

But that syntax is not working, what's the problem?

This is the error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE semester = 'Spring' AND year = 2010' at line 1
```

This is my 'teaches' table:

```
create table teaches(
    ID char(5),
    course_id varchar(8),
    sec_id varchar(8),
    semester varchar(6),
    year numeric(4,0),
    foreign key (course_id, sec_id, semester) references section (course_id, sec_id, semester)
)
```

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: that's the error message, i've edited my question.

Comment: What the structure of your table `teaches`?

Comment: What does the table structure have to do with the syntax of the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @Barmar, it's just how you suppose to ask question in a forum, you provide message error and table structure ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't have a space between `COUNT` and `(`. Change to

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
```

This is controlled by the [`ignore_space`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ignore_space) SQL mode setting. See also [Function Name Parsing and Resolution](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/function-resolution.html).